# Copy paste to another workbook with an if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy certain values from another sheet from another workbook in vba excel but im gettin err 1004. this is my code

```
Sub copiar()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range


    Set rng2 = Range("A2:A5")
    Set rng = Workbooks("perfumes.xlsx").Sheets("hoja").Range("A4:A10")


    For Each cell In rng2
        For Each cell2 In rng
            If cell2 = cell Then Workbooks("perfumes.xlsx").Worksheets("Hoja 1").Range("K" & cell2.Row).Copy Range("H" & cell.Row)
        Next cell2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Cant realise where the error occur
Im quite new to macros, migth need help, thanks

Comment: i have another question, does range() have a max row number? Because this is suppose to work with 20k rows

Comment: What's the error message? I don't think error 1004 always has the same message.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing wrong with your code, as such, the runtime error is a data problem so showing the data in your question will help. You can show the data by mocking up a table right here, or link to something like a Google spreadsheet, or in some way show examples of the data in a given row.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by the code so I changed it a bit to be more obvious what it is doing. This code does exactly what the OP's code does; no difference at all. Added some comments also.

```
Sub copiar()
    'Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    'Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range


    'active sheet
    'Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A5")
    'rng2.Select

    'compare sheet
    Dim hojaSheet As Worksheet
    Set hojaSheet = Workbooks("perfumes.xlsx").Sheets("hoja")
    'Set rng = hojaSheet.Range("A4:A10")

    'source sheet
    Dim hoja1Sheet As Worksheet
    Set hoja1Sheet = Workbooks("perfumes.xlsx").Sheets("hoja 1")

    'compare each cell in range in the activeSheet
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A5").Cells
        'to each cell in range in hojaSheet
        For Each cell2 In hojaSheet.Range("A4:A10").Cells
            'if matching then copy from hoja 1 sheet to ActiveSheet
            If cell2 = cell Then
                Call hoja1Sheet.Range("K" & cell2.Row).Copy(ActiveSheet.Range("H" & cell.Row))
                Debug.Print "copy from: Hoja 1!" & "K" & cell2.Row & " > " & "copy to: ActiveSheet!" & "H" & cell.Row
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Doesn't fix anything but may be useful if it helps clarify what the code is doing.

Comment: No. Now can you answer my question above? What was the error message?